# generate a successive collection of colors to be used a background color of ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone

Hello I want to apply a certain amount of grey to each item of ListBox successively i.e. from light to dark.My approach so far is this-

```
    public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = (int)random.Next(20,256) ;

            byte b = (byte)randomNumber;
            Color blueish = Color.FromArgb(255,b, b, b);
            return new SolidColorBrush((Color)blueish);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I am able to generate random amounts of grey, but I need Light to Dark feel. Please provide me suggestion of correcting my approach

Comment: You probably want to move `var random = new Random();` into a static field.  Also not sure why you are using a value converter when you not using the `value` parameter

Comment: I am using the converter so that this block of code is called for each member of the ListBox. And I also need to convert the computed color into SolidColorBrush too @Micky

Comment: OK.  Normally it is a function of the argument so you might find things suddenly change colours as you scroll up and down?  Not sure

Comment: Do you know how many items will be in the list? If so, choose a minimum and maximum value for `b` you feel comfortable with and then project the number of items to the range between min and max. For example: `byte min = 100; byte max = 200; int numberOfItems = 20; for (int index = 1; index <= numberOfItems; index++){ byte b = (max - min) / index; /* use b */ }`

Comment: http://files.channel9.msdn.com/wlwimages/ae054c0b4d7b402ab1239e6800c0220f/image%5B2%5D-56.png please refer to this image, I want the same feel using different shades of grey

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's impossible to even understand how the converter is being used, never mind the full context of the question or what a good answer would be. Please provide a good code example. The problem is _probably_ solvable using `AlternationIndex` and `AlternationCount`, where each item's alternation index is used to retrieve your desired shade of grey. But you're on your own figuring that out unless you can provide a better code example.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm able to understand [something like this is you trying to achieve](http://www.december.com/html/spec/color0.html)To generate light to dark feel you need successive color codes which can be based on value which you are converting to colors. So Random will not work here. You need to pass next color code value e.g. for each item increase value of variable b and then generate color. Hope this helps.